# Selecting from multiple tables in SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Ambiguous column name
>   'SchoolID'.'

I need to select a `SchoolName == SchoolID` and an `AcademicYear` from two combo-boxes that are found in two database tables `School-Info` and `School_AcademicYear`

Also `SchoolID` in `School_AcademicYear` is Foreign Key and its Primary Key in School_Info, I am using `inner join` to join these two tables but an error is occuring

> Ambiguous column name 'SchoolID'

```
con.Open();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT AcademicYearID,AcademicYear,SchoolID FROM School_AcademicYear  INNER JOIN School_Info ON School_AcademicYear.AcademicYearID = School_Info.SchoolID  where School_AcademicYear.AcademicYearID = '" + AcademicYearID + "'", con);
dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
dataGridViewSchoolNMergeAcYear.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Comment: When the two tables joined have columns with the same name and you refer to one of these columns in the SELECT list then you need to specify from which table are you getting the values

Comment: Gluing data into strings to make a query remains a bad, error prone, ineffective, dangerous and severely outdated way to compose SQL queries.  Always use Parameters.  Always.  See also [SQL Tutorial and Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Comment: @Steve i have a column with the same name which is SchoolID and selected that first SchoolID which is primary key is in School_Info table and second one which is foreign key is in School_AcademicYear table.. plz can you write me the code that you are telling me about

Comment: As everyone says, use parameters instead of string concatenation. An advantage of doing this is that you can get your query working in SQL Server Management Studio (after having DECLAREd and initialized the parameters),  and once the query is working, just copy/paste it into your code.  You might also want to look at Dapper, it simplifies a lot of this, with very little execution cost

Answer (score 2):

If you join two tables that contain columns with the same name and you refer to one of these columns in the SELECT list, then you need to specify from which table are you getting the values. So to solve this problem let's start using some [alias](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-alias/) for the table names. Using the alias in front of the column's name correctly identify the columns source table.
While at it, I have also changed your string concatenation to a parameterized query. It is a lot better because it avoids parsing errors and a well known security problem called [Sql Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017)

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.......))
{
    string cmdText = @"SELECT a.AcademicYearID,a.AcademicYear,i.SchoolID 
                       FROM School_AcademicYear a INNER JOIN School_Info i 
                         ON a.AcademicYearID = i.SchoolID  
                      WHERE a.AcademicYearID = @id";
    con.Open();
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, con);
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = AcademicYearID;
    dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dataGridViewSchoolNMergeAcYear.DataSource = dt;
}
```

To be complete this answer introduces also the [*using statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around the disposable connection object. In this way the connection is closed and *disposed* when the code exits the using block. Note that I suppose that *AcademicYearID* is a number and not a string so, the parameter is of type *SqlDbType.Int* instead of *NVarChar*.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple columns in those tables with name SchoolID.

You have to specify the column name, because sql cannot know which one you want. Example: `School_Info.SchoolID`

```
adp = new SqlDataAdapter(`
SELECT AcademicYearID,AcademicYear,School_Info.SchoolID 
FROM School_AcademicYear  
INNER JOIN School_Info ON School_AcademicYear.AcademicYearID = School_Info.SchoolID  
where School_AcademicYear.AcademicYearID = '` + AcademicYearID + "'", con);
```